# How to set config variables using p4python

Tags: perforce, p4python

I have tried doing below:

```
p4.run('configure', 'set', 'auth.ldap.timeout=30')
```

However, when I try below, I dont see this configuration set.

```
p4.run('configure', 'show')
```

Please let me know if i am missing something.

Comment: Did you check the output of the `p4 configure set` command to make sure that the setting was accepted (as opposed to getting, say, a permission error)?

Comment: You are right. This looks like a permission error. My P4 server doesn't allow to configure this setting.